# Note for monitoring buy/sell item list

Tags: java, console, e-commerce

I'm making note where you can add items that you buy or sell, any suggestions?

```
  public class Main {

    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String commands = "[-1]Quit, [0]Commands, [1]Available items, [2] Sold items, [3]Add, [4]Delete,"
            + " [5]Edit, [6]Sell. [7]Bilans [8]Details";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Storage storage = new Storage(5);

        storage.addItem();


        System.out.println("|   RESELL NOTE    |");
        System.out.println(commands);

        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            System.out.println("Choose option: (0 - print list)");


            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {

                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong command");
                    break;

                case -1:
                    System.out.println("QUIT");
                    flag = false;
                    break;

                case 0:
                    System.out.println(commands);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    storage.availableItems();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    storage.soldItems();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    storage.addItem();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    storage.removeItem();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("modify item");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    storage.sellItem();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    storage.bilans();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    storage.details();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Storage {

    private int maxCapacity;

    public Storage(int maxCapacity) {
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Map<Integer, Item> items = new TreeMap<>();


    public void availableItems() {
        System.out.println("Available items:");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getValue().sold) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ". " + entry.getValue().getName());
            }
        }
    }


    public void soldItems() {
        System.out.println("Sold items:");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().sold) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "." + entry.getValue().getName()
                        + " - (" + (entry.getValue().soldPrice - entry.getValue().price + "PLN profit)"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void addItem() {
        if (items.size() >= maxCapacity) {
            System.out.println("You cant add more items, storage full! (" + items.size() + "/" + maxCapacity + ")");
        } else {
            items.put(Item.assignId(), new Shoes("Piraty", 1500, 7, "red", 11));
            items.put(Item.assignId(), new Shoes("Belugi", 1500, 7, "red", 11));
            items.put(Item.assignId(), new Shoes("Zebry", 1500, 7, "red", 11));
            items.put(Item.assignId(), new Shoes("Creamy", 1500, 7, "red", 11));
            items.put(Item.assignId(), new Shoes("Sezame", 1500, 7, "red", 11));
            System.out.println("Item added");
        }
    }


    public void modifyItem() { // work in progress
        printInLine();
        System.out.println("\nPick item to modify: ");
        int id = in.nextInt();

        if (items.containsKey(id)) {
            System.out.println("Enter new name for " + items.get(id).getName());
            in.nextLine();
            String newName = in.nextLine();
            items.get(id).setName(newName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item not found");
        }
    }

    public void sellItem() {
        printInLine();
        System.out.println("\nChoose item to mark as sold: ");
        int id = in.nextInt();

        if (items.containsKey(id)) {
            items.get(id).setSold(true);
            System.out.println("How much did you get for " + items.get(id).getName() + "?: ");
            items.get(id).setSoldPrice(in.nextInt());
            System.out.println("You marked " + items.get(id).getName() + " as sold");
            System.out.println("Your profit is " + (items.get(id).soldPrice - items.get(id).price) + " PLN");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item not found");
        }
    }

    public void removeItem() {
        printInLine();
        System.out.println("\nChoose item to remove: ");
        int id = in.nextInt();

        if (items.containsKey(id)) {
            System.out.println(items.get(id).getName() + " removed");
            items.remove(id);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item not found");
        }
    }


    public void bilans() {

        int spendMoney = 0;
        int earnedMoney = 0;
        int profit = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getValue().sold) {
                spendMoney += entry.getValue().getPrice();
            } else {
                earnedMoney += entry.getValue().getSoldPrice();
                profit += (entry.getValue().getSoldPrice() - entry.getValue().getPrice());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You have already spended: " + spendMoney + " PLN");
        System.out.println("You sold items for: " + earnedMoney + " PLN");
        System.out.println("Current profit: " + profit + " PLN");

        if (earnedMoney > spendMoney) {
            System.out.println("Wow, you are on +");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Keep trying");
        }
    }

    public void details() {

        printInLine();
        System.out.print("\nPick item: ");
        int pickItem = in.nextInt();

        if (items.containsKey(pickItem)) {
            System.out.println("\n|  Details |");
            System.out.println("Name: " + items.get(pickItem).getName() +
                    "\nPrice: " + items.get(pickItem).getPrice() +
                    "\nCondition: " + items.get(pickItem).getCondition() + "/10" +
                    "\nColor: ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item not found");
        }
    }

    private void printInLine() {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getValue().isSold()) {
                System.out.print(" - " + entry.getKey() + "." + entry.getValue().getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Responsibilities](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_responsibility_principle)

A class should have only one responsibility. Robert C. Martin describes it with

> "There should never be more than one reason for a class to change".

When we have a look into `Storage` we can find multiple responsibilities:

- read inputs from the console

  > ```java
  > public void sellItem() {
  >     // ..
  >     int id = in.nextInt();
  >     // ..
  > }
  > ```
- provide the user with information

  > ```java
  > public void bilans() {
  >     // ..
  >     System.out.println("You have already spended: " + spendMoney + " PLN");
  >     System.out.println("You sold items for: " + earnedMoney + " PLN");
  >     System.out.println("Current profit: " + profit + " PLN");
  >     // ..
  > }
  > ```
- manage `items`

### Focus on one Responsibility

The class `Storage` should focus only on the logic to manage `items`.

### Advantage Over Multiple Responsibilities

Multiple companies bought your tool. Now imagine the following two scenarios:

5 Years later Company A and B want different customized information. You can't find a class like `InformationFormate`. But after some search you found it in `Storage`, you go into it and *change* it. You built an `if`-statement to check for A or B and the default case to print some information.

Now company C calls you and sad that you should build them a graphical user interface. And again you go into the `Storage` after you didn't found a class like `UserInterface` and build a new `if`-statement to check for C and have build your gui logic into it and for all other the text user interface.

You can see, that with the number of responsibilities the number of possible changes grows for one class and it gets bigger and bigger. Additional when you search for these task you will not think at first that displaying information would be in a class named `Storage`.

## [Replace Conditional With Polymorphism](http://wiki.c2.com/?ReplaceConditionalWithPolymorphism)

> ```java
> switch (answer) {
>     default:
>         System.out.println("Wrong command");
>         break;
>    case -1:
>         System.out.println("QUIT");
>         flag = false;
>         break;
>    case 0:
>         System.out.println(commands);
>         break;
>    case 1:
>         // ...
>    case 8:
>         storage.details();
> }
> ```

What this huge `switch` tries to express is

> Find a *command* by a number and *execute* the associated task.

We could simplyfy the `switch` with

```java
Command command = commandFactory.getBy(answer);
boolean shouldContinueProgram = command.execute();
```

## [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

In the Unit above you found

> ```java
> Command command = commandFactory.provide(answer);
> command.execute();
> ```

This is using the factory method pattern.

The `commandFactory` is an object which gives you the correct Instance of type `Command`, which is an interface and could be one of your 8 given commands to choose.

```java
interface Command {
    boolean execute();
}

class WrongInput implements Command {
    @Override
    public boolean execute() {
        System.out.println("Wrong command");
        return true;
    }
}

class Quite implements Command {
    @Override
    public boolean execute() {
        System.out.println("Wrong command");
        return false;
    }
}

interface CommandFactory<T> {
    Command provide(T t);
}

class NumberCommandFactory implements CommandFactory<Integer> {

    private Map<Integer, Command> numberByCommand;

    public NumberCommandFactory() {
        numberByCommand.put(-1, new Quite());
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Command provide(Integer numberOfCommand) {
        return numberByCommand.getOrDefault(numberOfCommand, new WrongInput());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         boolean flag = true;
>         while (flag) {
>             System.out.println("Choose option: (0 - print list)");
>
>
>             int answer = in.nextInt();
>             switch (answer) {
>
>                 default:
>                     System.out.println("Wrong command");
>                     break;
>
>                 case -1:
>                     System.out.println("QUIT");
>                     flag = false;
>                     break;
>
>                 case 0:
>                     System.out.println(commands);
>                     break;
>                 case 1:
>                     storage.availableItems();
>                     break;
>                 case 2:
>                     storage.soldItems();
>                     break;
>                 case 3:
>                     storage.addItem();
>                     break;
>                 case 4:
>                     storage.removeItem();
>                     break;
>                 case 5:
>                     System.out.println("modify item");
>                     break;
>                 case 6:
>                     storage.sellItem();
>                     break;
>                 case 7:
>                     storage.bilans();
>                     break;
>                 case 8:
>                     storage.details();
>             }
>         }
> ```

Consider

```
    public static void loop() {
        for (;;) {
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("QUIT");
                    return;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println(commands);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    storage.availableItems();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    storage.soldItems();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    storage.addItem();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    storage.removeItem();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("modify item");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    storage.sellItem();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    storage.bilans();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    storage.details();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong command");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now we don't need the `flag` variable.  We simply loop forever until the user enters -1 and we return from the method.

This gives us the option of moving the method to a separate class, simplifying the `Main` class and allowing the code to be used in more than one program.

I find it easier to read with the `default` case at the end and with it being the only case without a `break`.  That's not to say that that the other form is not perfectly functional.  But unless you are making use of [fallthrough](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-fall-through-switch-statements), I just find it simpler this way.

Consider displaying the list of commands any time an invalid command is given.  Because sometimes a person can't remember that 0 will print the list of commands.  And saying "print list" might not suggest to them that it will print a list of commands rather than items.

#### Separate logic and display

You have

> ```
>     public void availableItems() {
>         System.out.println("Available items:");
>         for (Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
>             if (!entry.getValue().sold) {
>                 System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ". " + entry.getValue().getName());
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

and

> ```
>     private void printInLine() {
>         for (Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
>             if (!entry.getValue().isSold()) {
>                 System.out.print(" - " + entry.getKey() + "." + entry.getValue().getName());
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

What if we instead had

```
    public static void printItemsOnSeparateLines(Iterable<Item> items) {
        for (Item item : items) {
            System.out.println(item.getID() + ". " + item.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void printItemsOnSameLine(Iterable<Item> items) {
        for (Item item : items) {
            System.out.print(" - " + item.getID() + "." + item.getName());
        }
    }

    public List<Item> findAvailableItems() {
        return items.stream.filter(item -> !item.isSold()).collect(Collectors.toList);
    }

    public List<Item> findSoldItems() {
        return items.stream.filter(item -> item.isSold()).collect(Collectors.toList);
    }
```

Now we use them like

```
System.out.println("Available items:");
printItemsOnSeparateLines(findAvailableItems());
```

And our methods are each individually simpler.

I also changed from a property access to `isSold`.  This reads better to me and is better encapsulated.

Now if we come up with new criteria, we can add a new simple method and just reuse our existing display method.  Or we can add a new display and reuse our business logic.

This would require `Item` to include its identifier, which may just be in the `Map` keys.

#### Refactor common code into new methods

> ```
>     public void sellItem() {
>         printInLine();
>         System.out.println("\nChoose item to mark as sold: ");
>         int id = in.nextInt();
>
>         if (items.containsKey(id)) {
>             items.get(id).setSold(true);
>             System.out.println("How much did you get for " + items.get(id).getName() + "?: ");
>             items.get(id).setSoldPrice(in.nextInt());
>             System.out.println("You marked " + items.get(id).getName() + " as sold");
>             System.out.println("Your profit is " + (items.get(id).soldPrice - items.get(id).price) + " PLN");
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("Item not found");
>         }
>     }
> ```

This could be

```
    public void sellItem() {
        printItemsOnSameLine(findAvailableItems());
        Item item = selectItem("\nChoose item to mark as sold: ");
        if (item == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (item.isSold()) {
            System.out.println("That item already sold.");
            return;
        }

        item.setSold(true);
        System.out.println("How much did you get for " + item.getName() + "?: ");
        item.setSoldPrice(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("You marked " + item.getName() + " as sold");
        System.out.println("Your profit is " + (item.soldPrice - item.price) + " PLN");
    }
```

with

```
    public Item selectItem(String query) {
        System.out.println(query);

        Item item = items.get(in.nextInt();
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Now we don't have to continually rewrite the same code (four times).  If we want to select an item, we can just call that method.

I also handled a condition that the original code did not.  What if someone entered the ID of an already sold item?

Rather than repeatedly writing `items.get(id)`, this code just uses `item`.

We don't have to call `containsKey`, as we can get the same behavior by simply calling `get`, which we have to call anyway.  And now we don't have to carry around the ID.

#### Logic mistake?

> ```
>         for (Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
>             if (!entry.getValue().sold) {
>                 spendMoney += entry.getValue().getPrice();
>             } else {
>                 earnedMoney += entry.getValue().getSoldPrice();
>                 profit += (entry.getValue().getSoldPrice() - entry.getValue().getPrice());
>             }
>         }
> ```

Later you compare `spendMoney` and `earnedMoney`.  But the two aren't comparable.  They are on different items.  Consider

```
        for (Item item : values()) {
            spentMoney += item.getPrice();
            if (item.isSold()) {
                earnedMoney += item.getSoldPrice();
                profit += item.getSoldPrice() - item.getPrice();
            }
        }
```

Now we have the amount of money spent to procure all the items compared to the amount of money earned on the current sold items.  We know if we are currently ahead.  Or we can look at profit to see if we are ahead on the items already sold.

I also changed from `entrySet` to just `values` because you were never using the key.  So we can just say `item` rather than `entry.getValue()`.

I changed `spendMoney` to `spentMoney` to be consistent with `earnedMoney`.